# ogr2ogr Conversion Clockwise to Counterclockwise?

Tags: qgis, polygon, ogr2ogr, multi-polygon

Looking for the right combination of ogr2ogr parameters to get a .shp bundle to GeoJSON and reverse the Coordinate pairs. I recognize that ESRI defines Polygons as clockwise (http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) but GeoJSON RFC defines Polygons counterclockwise.

Current command is

```
ogr2ogr -progress -overwrite -f GeoJSON -s_srs "EPSG: 3857" -t_srs crs:84 file0.json file0.shp
```

which makes GeoJSON that is invalid when consumed by other tools that follow the RFC at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946.

Any ideas? If this needs to be run twice to convert to an intermediate format that's fine, if there is another (command line or automation) tool, I'm open to that also.

Comment: Are you sure that it's the order of vertices that's causing the problem, if the spec for GeoJSON says counter clockwise for the exterior ring then OGR2OGR should do that, it could be a bowtie (self intersection) or empty geometry that is causing your problem.

Comment: The shapefile spec specifies right-hand rule, which differs from clockwise on interior rings. In fact, more Esri tools use left-hand rule than right. It's generally the translator's responsibility for handling ring orientation issues, not something you need to handle yourself.

Comment: Calling the ESRI rule as right hand rule is misleading because in mathematics (and in the GeoJSON specification) the right hand rule means just the opposite.

Answer (score 3):

Read again the documentation of the GDAL GeoJSON driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html and modify your command to produce GeoJSON that follows RFC 7946 by adding a layer creation option `-lco RFC7946=YES`.

Excerpt from the documentation:

> **RFC 7946 write support**
>
> By default, the driver will write GeoJSON files
> following GeoJSON 2008 specification. When specifying the RFC7946=YES
> creation option, the RFC 7946 standard will be used instead.
>
> The
> differences between the 2 versions are mentioned in Appendix B of RFC
> 7946 and recalled here for what matters to the driver: >
>
> Coordinates
> must be geographic over the WGS 84 ellipsoid, hence if the spatial
> reference system specified at layer creation time is not EPSG:4326,
> on-the-fly reprojection will be done by the driver. >
>
> Polygons will be
> written such as to follow the right-hand rule for orientation
> (counterclockwise external rings, clockwise internal rings).
>
> The
> values of a “bbox” array are “[west, south, east, north]”, not “[minx,
> miny, maxx, maxy]”
>
> Some extension member names (see previous section
> about round/tripping) are forbidden in the FeatureCollection, Feature
> and Geometry objects.
>
> The default coordinate precision is 7 decimal
> digits after decimal separator.

There is also a note in the RFC that some developers obviously have not taken seriously:

> Note: the [GJ2008] specification did not discuss linear ring winding order.  For backwards
> compatibility, parsers SHOULD NOT reject    Polygons that do not
> follow the right-hand rule.